# How to set custom ListView cell background colors?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-selector

I need to add custom logic for setting a ListView background color. I want read items to be displayed grey. I know I can call setBackgroundColor on the view itself but that seems to mess up the default behavior of the ListView selector has pressed/disabled cell colors. It will no longer show the proper bluish background animation when pressed.

In the gmail app you can see a similar effect with the read mail entries. If you tap them the correct animation of background color takes place.

Comment: You could try `setDrawSelectorOnTop(true)` on those cells. It should make the selection color work again even with a changed background. All tough it will make other components in the cell invisible when the selection animation is visible.

Comment: Since, you have custom list view. You may want to set your item layouts background color to be gray and not the lists background color. List background color applies to all list and not the items. So basically in your getView method. You can check if the item was readd then change the color of layout containing item and if not keep the default color that you have.